# Wordpress pagenavi output at top of page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a custom post type through a plugin and I'm using the pagenavi plugin. The page navi plugin works fine apart from it appears at the top of the content instead of at the end of the table. I've tried all sorts of placements with the wp_pagenavi() function and all don't work. I need help.

code is:

```
foreach ( $query_pdf->posts as $file) {

                    $string = '<td><a href='. $file->guid .' target="_blank">Download</a></td>';
            }


                $output .= '<tr>';
                $output .= '<td>'. get_the_title() .'</td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . get_the_date() . '</td>';
                $output .= sprintf( $string );
                $output .= '<tr>';



        endwhile;

        $output .= '</tr></table>' . wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $success ));

    endif;

        return  $output;
```

css is:

```
.wp-pagenavi {
clear: none !important;
}

.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi span {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #333;
border: none;
padding: 10px 5px;
margin: 4px;
color: #fff;
}

.wp-pagenavi a:hover, .wp-pagenavi span.current {
background-color: #3498db;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed with adding echo=> false to the end:

```
$output .= '</tr></table>' . wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $success, 'echo'=>false ) );
```